My bathroom sewer vent is in the bathroom, it does not go out the roof?
My toilet is right next to my sink they are only about 10 inches away from each other. Right in-between them is a vent pipe. There's literally 5 inches from pipe to toilet, and 5 inches from pipe to sink. The vent pipe stops right below the top of the sink. It does not go outside at all? Is this safe/legal?

A picture would sure help.  Is the vent pipe open?

Is it an admittance valve?

Open vent pipes are not allowed ever inside the home. Air Admittance Valves (AAVs) are allowed in certain circumstances and certain jurisdiction.
Look at some images of AAVs and see if that is what you have at the top of the vent. If it is an open pipe (just a hole in the top), you should, at a minimum, put an AAV in; even if not to code in your locale. You don't want sewer gas coming back into your home.
The downside of AAVs are that they WILL eventually fail (sewer gas smell or it stops allowing free draining). But that really isn't a big problem; you simply replace the AAV and you're all good again.
